# Present tense simple - Present tense progressive

Tags: tense

Are both correct?

> My brother **sits** at his desk and he **does** his homework.
>
> My brother **is sitting** at his desk and he **is doing** his homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct but they would be used in different contexts.

If I were to ask: "What is your brother doing?" You might reply:

> My brother is sitting at his desk and he is doing his homework.

That's a typical statement of what someone is doing at this moment.

But if the question were: "What does you brother do before he goes out on a Friday night?", the answer might be:

> My brother sits at his desk and he does his homework.

So the former describes what your brother is doing at present, and the latter is used to describe an habitual or repeated action, generally with a time reference, eg: on Sundays, each evening, in summer and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!!. That means when there is no question I can write both. - My daughter had this in an Englisch Test and the teacher crossed out her answers and gave her 0 points. She had to fill in present tense simple or present tense progressive: My brother......(sit) at his desk and he......(do) his homework. My daughter wrotes:  My brother sits at his desk and he does his homework. There was no question before.  So I can go tomorrow to the teacher that he gives her 2 points and a better mark.

Comment: @MichaelaFriedmann Sadly, language questions are often confusing and ambiguous while teachers can be fickle and resentful of being challenged. Be tactful!

Comment: OK, thank you, I will try my best to get the 2 points.